# Windows phone 8 Bluetooth development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating an app to connect to a remote device. The following line of code is used to find all peers.

```
  var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
```

Now I need to declare peers as a class variable(instead of using it locally). Can some body tell me the datatype of peer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.findallpeersasync) it should be

```
IAsyncOperation <IReadOnlyList<PeerInformation>>  peers;
```